# Heroku app coming up blank with weird console messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

I have a small MERN stack app that runs great locally. After a successful build on Heroku I try to deploy it and get a blank screen. No `failed to deploy` message telling me to check the logs. Just blank.

In my browser console log i get these 3 weird errors that I cannot identify or know what to do with:

[image: Heroku blank page with console log messages]

has anyone ever encountered these?
I have no idea what .chunk.js could be

Comment: If you visit your asset URLs (for example: http://secret-brushlands-43080.herokuapp.com/static/js/1.9ec4eb3c.chunk.js) you'll find they're serving HTML instead. I suspect you've got some sort of "send all routes to the app" configuration that's overriding your static files like JS and CSS.

Comment: xml is being fed to a json parser somehow ??  review your prod ( heroku ) config and verify that config related files are included in the push ( heroku ) and that your ENV is set correct in heroku site dashboard,.,

Comment: how do i check the env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it ended up being the relative path to my build was incorrect

in the boilerplate i started with it was set to:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(passport.session()); app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')));
};
```

it needed to be

```
app.use(passport.session()); app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));
```